# Is the condition number (SVD) a measure of the orthogonality of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd, singular-values

We say a matrix is well-conditioned when its condition number is close to 1, and is ill-conditioned when the condition number is large.  I'm puzzled whether the condition number has a simple interpretation?  Does it tell us some basic property about a matrix?  It appears to have high correlation with the "orthogonality" of a matrix.  Not sure if this is true, or how true this is.

Consider two extremes.

First, suppose $A$ is a most well-conditioned square (for simplicity) matrix, having condition number of $1$.  Then an SVD of $A$ is necessarily of the form $A=U(\sigma I)V^*$, where $U$ and $V$ are unitary and $\sigma>0$.  Apparently, $A$ is itself a scaled unitary matrix, and its columns (and rows) are orthogonal.

Secondly, suppose $A$ is a most ill-conditioned, say $3\times 3$ for simplicity, matrix, with singular values of $1, 0, 0$.  Hence $A=U\,\mathrm{diag}(1, 0, 0)\,V^*$, where $U=[u_1,u_2, u_3]$ and $V=[v_1, v_2, v_3]$.  In other words, $A=u_1v_1^*$.  If we denote $A$ by $A=[a_1, a_2, a_3]$, and measure the orthogonality of its columns by $\gamma_{ij}\triangleq \vert a_i^* a_j\vert/(\Vert a_i\Vert \Vert a_j \Vert)$.  Apparently, $\gamma_{ij}=1$ for all $i, j$, so $A$ has "the least orthogonal" columns.  Same for its rows.

Can this be generalized somehow?  Clearly, when $\gamma_{ij}=0$ for any $i\ne j$, we have the first case, a most well-conditioned matrix.  And when $\gamma_{ij}=1$ for some $i\ne j$, we have the second case.  The converse however is not true for the second case, which does not necessarily require $\gamma_{ij}=1$ for some $i\ne j$, but simply requires columns or rows to be linearly dependent.  So I'm still puzzled: Is the condition number higher when the columns (rows) of a matrix is "less orthogonal" (or more correlated)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given any $k > 0 $, we can always find a square matrix $A$ which has condition number $k$ and uncorrelated columns : $A = \text{diag}(k,1)$ for example. Thus, the columns of a matrix with finite condition number can be 'arbitrarily uncorrelated'.

On the other hand, a singular matrix must have linearly dependent columns, and so the columns must in particular be correlated.

A more interesting question is the following : How correlated can the columns of a matrix be if it has finite condition number $k$? To answer this, we work in a more abstract set up.

Consider a linear endomorphism $ A : V \to V$, where $V$ is a finite dimensional inner product space. Then, the correlation between the images of vectors $v$ and $w$ under $A$ is :

$\text{corr}(Av,Aw) = \dfrac{\langle Av,Aw \rangle}{\sqrt{\langle Av,Av \rangle \langle Aw,Aw \rangle}} = \dfrac{\langle v,A^{*}A, w \rangle}{\sqrt{\langle v,A^{*}A, v \rangle \langle w,A^{*}A, w \rangle}} = \dfrac{{\langle v, w \rangle}_{A}}{\sqrt{{\langle v, v \rangle}_{A} {\langle w, w \rangle}_{A}}} $

where $\langle v, w \rangle_{A} : = \langle v,A^{*}A, w \rangle $ defines a positive semi-definite bilinear form. The question we ask is the following :

For $v$ and $w$ in $V$, with $\langle v , w \rangle = 0$ and $|| v || = ||w || = 1$, how big can $\text{corr}(Av,Aw)$ be? Exploiting the scale invariance of the correlation, this is equivalent to :

$$\underset{\langle v,w \rangle = 0 \ \text{and} \ \langle v,v \rangle _{A} =  \langle w,w \rangle _{A} = 1 }{\max}{\text{corr}(Av,Aw)}$$

Note that the normalised eigenvectors of $A^{*} A$ form an orthonormal basis $\mathcal{B} = \{ b_1, b_2 \cdots b_n\}$ which is uncorrelated : $\langle b_{i} , b_{j} \rangle _{A} = \sigma_{i} ^{2} \delta_{ij}$, where $\sigma_{\min} = \sigma_{1} \leq \sigma_{2} \cdots \leq \sigma_{n} = \sigma_{\max}$ are the singular values of $A$. Writing $v = \sum v_{i} b_{i} $ and $ w = \sum w_{i} b_{i} $, the problem is reduced to :

$$\max {\sum{v_i w_i \sigma_{i}^{2}}} \ $$  subject to  $\sum v_{i} w_{i} = 0 \ \text{and} \ \sum v_{i}^{2} \sigma_{i}^{2} = \sum w_{i}^{2} \sigma_{i}^{2} = 1$

A Lagrange multiplier argument shows that the maximum is attained at $ v = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} (b_1 + b_n) $ and $ w = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} (b_n - b_1
)$, and equals $\frac{k^2 - 1}{k^2 + 1}$, where $k = \frac{\sigma_\text{max}}{\sigma_\text{min}}$ is the condition number of $A$.

Thus the more ill conditioned a matrix, the more correlated the columns *can* be.

Comment: Cool.  Thanks a lot!  One question about the last sentence, i.e. "Thus the more ill conditioned a matrix, the more correlated the columns can be."  Not quite sure why you'd say so.  Isn't it (corr($Av, Aw$)) the correlation of the images of two orthogonal vectors instead?  Why would you say it's the correlation of the columns of $A$?

Comment: While the key takeaway should be exactly that, the only reason I made that last statement was to answer your original question which asked about correlation of the columns. Note that the columns of the matrix can be thought to be images of orthonormal basis vectors!